# Shell Programing - Get value in while loop after done

Tags: loops, while-loop, sh

I have this chunk of code:

```
var1=0

while loop
do
var1="1";
done

echo "$var1";
```

THe result was 0, instead of 1. However, if I echo inside the while loop, it is output as 1. I know .sh can't pass a sub process (child process) to a parent process. How do I alter code to reflect the `var1` changes in the loop after the loop ends?

I saw export as an option but I not sure how to implement it.

Comment: I think you should provide more details, like what is your looping condition "loop" because of no specified condition, the flow never enters the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to provide  a sample looping condition to your question "*How do I alter code to reflect the var1 changes in the loop after the loop ends?*"

```
 var1="0"
 loop="1"

 while [ $var1 -ne $loop ]
 do
      var1="1"
 done
 echo $var1
```

Hope we'll be able to help you better after you provide more details.